# Strange font behaviour when changing font-weight values through an input form

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to achieve a sort-of-Microsoft Word control panel, which allows you to edit and format text. It works but it's not smooth at all. When I change the `font-weight` or the `font-style` of the element, the font quickly changes to the browser's default one before loading the selected one. Is there a way to at least improve this performance?

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but it could because of the repaint time.

Comment: try preloading fonts

Comment: Not sure, it actually occurs during the first few times. After that, it's all smooth.

Comment: Then, do as @jeshu911 suggested.

Comment: 1) Which font are you using. 2) What font-weights are you using, 3) What font-styles are you using 4) Does your font supports these font weight/style variants? 5) If its a custom font are you preloading all font variants?

Comment: Yes, the fonts do support these properties. However, preloading the fonts WAS the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

maybe the font-weight you set at this moment doesn't exist for that font family.

Did you try with other font?

Comment: I did, the same thing occurs. I'm going to try preloading the fonts and I'll tell if it's the solution in a few moments.